# How to split long VARCHAR text into each word a column

Tags: t-sql, split, cpu-word

I am looking to split e.g. ' Black Granite Hearth to t-shape, 54 x 26 ' into seperate columns each with simple t-sql code - not complicated logic.

```
with C1 as 
(
select ProductName, SUBSTRING(ProductName, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', ProductName))  as firstword,
SUBSTRING(ProductName, CHARINDEX(' ', ProductName), LEN(ProductName))  as secondword
from [dbo].[AProducts]
),
C2 AS 
(
select firstword, secondword
from C1
)

select firstword, SUBSTRING(secondword, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', secondword)) as z from C2
```

THIS IS PRODUCTNAME EXTRACT:

```
To credit against Invoice 104 - overcharged in error
Black Granite Hearth to t-shape, 54 x 26
Black Granite Header 38 x 5, Slips 32 x 5
Nero Zimbabwe 30mm worktops, supplied and fitted
```

Comment: Please don't SHOUT AT US. There is no reason to post your question in ALL CAPS. It won't get you an answer any faster, it makes text harder to read, and it's really rude and annoying. When you look at all of the posts listed on the main page, you don't see any (except yours) in ALL CAPS, because it's inappropriate to do so. Please stop now.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Odd request to go horizontal vs. vertical.  Without going dynamic, you run the risk of dropping words, but the following is easy to expand if necessary.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (PRODUCTNAME varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('To credit against Invoice 104 - overcharged in error')
,('Black Granite Hearth to t-shape, 54 x 26')
,('Black Granite Header 38 x 5, Slips 32 x 5')
,('Nero Zimbabwe 30mm worktops, supplied and fitted')

Select A.*
      ,C.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( Select CleanString = replace(replace(replace(A.ProductName,' x ','x'),',',''),' - ',' ') ) B
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1  = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]' ,'varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2  = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]' ,'varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3  = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]' ,'varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos4  = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]' ,'varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos5  = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]' ,'varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos6  = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]' ,'varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos7  = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]' ,'varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos8  = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[8]' ,'varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos9  = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[9]' ,'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(B.CleanString,' ','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as X
             ) C
```

**Returns**

[image]